# SHOPIFY Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: Access denied for orders field

Tags: graphql, shopify, scopes, shopify-api

I got this error to fetch orders with '@shopify/koa-shopify-auth'from a PUBLIC app.

Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: Access denied for orders field.

The query is like this.

```
orders(first: 10, after: $cursor, query: $query, reverse: true) {
  edges {
    cursor
    node {
      currentTotalPriceSet {
        presentmentMoney {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
      }
      tags
    }
  }
  pageInfo {
    hasNextPage
  }
}
```

with $query like this

```
let query = campaigns
   .map((campaign) => `tag:'FreeGiftCampaignId: ${campaign.id}'`)
   .join(" OR ");
```

I added reverse: true, and the scopes are correctly set

```
SCPOPES: read_orders,read_all_orders,write_orders,read_products,read_discounts,write_discounts,write_script_tags
```

Also the app has been approved for read_all_orders

The strange thing about this issue is that it's not happening to every merchant only some of them have this issue

if i query the scopes for a failing merchant (just before the failing call)
i got this which seems totaly fine

```
[
  {
    "handle": "read_all_orders"
  },
  {
    "handle": "write_orders",
  },
  {
    "handle": "read_products",
  },
  {
    "handle": "write_discounts",
  },
  {
    "handle": "write_script_tags",
  },
  {
    "handle": "read_orders",
  },
  {
    "handle": "read_discounts",
  },
  {
    "handle": "read_script_tags",
  }
]
```

also the 2 preceding calls which get a product and a collection fails with thoses errors

```
message: "Product access denied"
message: "Collection access denied"
```

So it definitely seems like a scope issue.

but what i am not getting is:

1. it is not happening to everyone only a few merchant
2. when checking the scopes for the failing merchant they seems fine